# Search a node in a strange binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a binary tree, it is strange: the root is the highest number, and the other go decreasing...
(Example: Huffman tree)
I need to make an algorithm that searches a key inside it.

I tried a lot but I had no idea how to do it =(

Any suggestion please?

For example like this[image]

Comment: Read about heap tree(max to be specific), that will help you

Comment: If that is how your tree is then you don't have much choice but to try every node in the tree. But if you need to do that you've probably chosen the wrong data structure or misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: @Philipp: It's not a heap. Heaps are filled (except the last row, which is partially filled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tree in the [image you showed us](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Coding_Theory/Huffman_Coding) is a Huffman Tree. The nodes inside this tree represent the **number of occurrences of the keys under that node**. A node gives you absolutely no information about the keys that can be found from that node.

As you have no information about the keys in a subtree, you have to **go through the whole tree** to find a key inside it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check every node in the tree.

If performance is important, create another mapping, a hash table or a binary search tree. In the example you showed you're searching for a single character, for which you can just use an array with 256 entires if you use an 8bit charset.